# unable to add files using git add -u command

Tags: git

I am trying files with a pattern *.zip but unable to add using the pattern *.zip. I am unable to do so.
**Steps Used:**
Using git add command, added 5.zip file to the index.
then tried to add other zip files using *.zip using git add -u *.zip.
but 7.zip and 8.zip are not getting updated. Why?

```
C:\Users\myname\gitlearn\root>git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   1.pub
#       new file:   2.pub
#       new file:   New Microsoft Publisher Document.pub 
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       ../.gitconfig
#       5.zip
#       7.zip
#       8.zip
#       New Text Document - Copy.txt
#       New Text Document.txt
C:\Users\myname\gitlearn\root>git add 5.zip
C:\Users\myname\gitlearn\root>git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   1.pub
#       new file:   2.pub
#       new file:   5.zip
#       new file:   New Microsoft Publisher Document.pub
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       ../.gitconfig
#       7.zip
#       8.zip
#       New Text Document - Copy.txt
#       New Text Document.txt
C:\Users\myname\gitlearn\root>git add -u *.zip
C:\Users\myname\gitlearn\root>git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   1.pub
#       new file:   2.pub
#       new file:   5.zip
#       new file:   New Microsoft Publisher Document.pub
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       ../.gitconfig
#       7.zip
#       8.zip
#       New Text Document - Copy.txt
#       New Text Document.txt
C:\Users\myname\gitlearn\root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not use `-u` in your command. This option forces to update only the files which are already in the index (5.zip) and ignore the non-indexed files (7.zip and 8.zip).

Try with `git add *.zip` instead.

Comment: It worked well,  I was incorrectly using -u option to update the files